# what is the pin connectors called that is used on through hole pcb with space above for swappable microcontrollers (or other devices)?

Tags: pcb, prototyping

I have a medium size through hole PCB for prototyping. I remember a project in school that gave us a female to male connector that allowed us plug in a microcontroller (atmega328p, but could be any length of ucontroller) by hand without soldering or directly wire-wrapping the atmega's pins.

It provides black spacing above the PCB for the microcontroller's pins, but we solder the bottom through hole side (I believe the through hole was the standard 2.54 mm round opening). And the above female accepted the standard 2.54 mm as well.

Not sure of the length of the metal. I just remember the black portion was that standard plastic material that would melt when applying too much time soldering the metal.

I think its through hole DIP socket header but when I google that I can't find it exactly.

Comment: sounds like some sort of `IC socket`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sounds like some sort of `IC socket`

ordinary flat pin
[image]

or perhaps machined pin:
 [image: machined pin socket]

But sometimes a lever-operated zero insertion force socket is used
[image]

Comment: its like the 2nd but more space for the microcontroller's pins to fit snug. (longer of the black portion).

Comment: or yea it looks like its the first. i found a set im going to buy and try. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

DIP (or DIL) IC socket. If the IC needs to be removed repeatedly you may wish to use a ZIF DIP socket.